# Trying to make a function that goes through every file and pull out every video file in a given directory

Tags: python

I was downloading videos on the internet and decided to also practice my coding skills while I'm at it, so I made a python script to help me organize files. As you can see, the current function does do what I want it to do to an extent, but I can't figure out a method to just find just Folders and not try to make every single file into a directory which results in the code crashing.

```
def pullout():
    for files in os.listdir():
        movehere = filepath
        newpath = filepath + "\\" + files
        #print(newpath)
        os.chdir(newpath)
        for files in os.listdir():
            if files.endswith(".mp4"):
                shutil.move(files, movehere)

filepath = input("Enter file path\n")
os.chdir(filepath)
```

To find all types of video files I guess I'll just add more in the `endswith()` like .wmv, .flv, .avi, etc.

Folders have no file extension which is a way to identify them but can't find a method that helps with that so that's useless.

Comment: Look into `os.walk`.

Comment: 1. `os.path.isdir` exists, no need to guess on the name 2. You probably want to use `os.walk` instead of implementing your own logic to enter subdirectories

Comment: Also I wouldn't use `os.chdir` but instead just use full filepaths and pass them as arguments to the specific functions

Comment: @SitiSchu I can see how `os.path.isdir` can be useful. I'm guessing they go in between  `for files in os.listdir():` and `movehere = filepath`?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `os.walk` first instead of trying to use `os.listdir` for this

Comment: @SitiSchu I can't, that's one of the many functions I'm currently making, I'm planning to make dozens more and make an actual app to submit to my professor.